# Yahoo online multiplayer games: one Socket per opened window / game?

Tags: silverlight, sockets

I would like to know how they do it, or what is the best approach for doing it.
Both server side and client side are in question.
After finishing my gaming site, the next phase is to provide multiplayer games in Silverlight.

For me, the simplest method seems to have one Socket per window / game opened, but it may be more reliable to have 1 Socket connection to handle all windows / games opened by a client.
I am wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why multiplex if you don't have too?  Having a socket per game opened seems like the easier approach.